# ReactNative with remote repository

Tags: github, react-native

I have developed a project which works fine on my system , then I checked in my source code in remote git hub repo but now people are complaining that the project does not load on there machine , so I also tried to download the repo in a folder then it failed for me also with a error "ld: library not found for -lRCTWebSocketDebugger" . I tried to download some more project from Github and they also have same problem 
https://github.com/asamiller/den
https://github.com/ajaybeniwal/ReactNativeTransportApp

Answer (score 0):

May you should

```
pod  'React/RCTWebSocketDebugger'
```